# Visual Frame Around Command Line Application

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am writing a command line application in Ruby using [GLI](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli).  My app uses the [Bio](http://bioruby.org/rdoc/) gem to query [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) and print out bibliographic information for the results, one by one, to the terminal. The user is prompted for a small amount of information using [HighLine](https://github.com/JEG2/highline), this is recorded to a database, and the display cycle repeats.  Here is example output:

[image]

I would like to create a frame around my application as it runs to show the key bindings for exit, help commands etc.  The text editor `nano` provides an example:

[image]

How can I create a similar frame around my program output, while allowing scrolling within that frame?  Is there a cross-platform way to do this?  I'd like to handle both Windows and *nix.

Comment: Programs like `nano` are written using the [`curses` library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html). How your application is written, apart from command line parsing done with GLI?

Comment: @toro2k My app uses the [Bio](http://bioruby.org/rdoc/) gem to query [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) and print bibliographic information to the terminal.  The user is prompted for a small amount of information using [HighLine](https://github.com/JEG2/highline), this is recorded to a database, then another article is loaded from PubMed.  Will using `curses` will allow for an application that works on Windows?

Comment: No, I don't think `curses` are ported to Windows, but don't know for sure. By the way, since you have implemented user interaction using `HighLine` probably `curses` are not the tool for the job. Can you post a sample of the actual output and how you would it to look like?

Comment: @toro2k I edited the post to show program output.  What I want is to frame that output nano-style and to offer the ability to scroll without disturbing the frame.  Thanks for your help!